# Options for Kendo MVVM animation binding

Tags: animation, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have seen some examples in the documentation and the demos that the data-animation attribute can be used to switch off animations on a widget by specifying data-animation="false".

My question is: how can I define other settings for animations.  For example:

```
{
    animation: {
        // fade-out current tab over 1000 milliseconds
        close: {
            duration: 1000,
            effects: "fadeOut"
        },
       // fade-in new tab over 500 milliseconds
       open: {
           duration: 500,
           effects: "fadeIn"
       }
   }
}
```

I cannot find documentation anywhere on how to define animation configuration like the one above using the data-animation attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define it as:

```
data-animation="{ close: { duration: 1000, effects: 'fade:out' }, open: { duration: 500, effects: 'fade:in' } }"
```

Example for a window:

```
<div id="dialog" data-role="window" data-animation="{ close: { duration: 1000, effects: 'fade:out' }, open: { duration: 500, effects: 'fade:in' } }" data-visible="false">
    This is the content of the window
</div>
```

See it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/XNcmt/70/

Answer (score 1):

The relevant documentation is [this here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/data-attribute-initialization#configuration).

You can can basically use the same values (primitives like boolean or object literals) for declarative initialization; the only difference is that it's a string representation of the object.

See OnaBai's answer for an example.

Comment: And in addition to what Lars Höppner says :-) just need to take care when escaping strings that might be a little tricky